# What is the role of Director of Public Q&A?

Tags: support, company

I gather that the company that runs the Stack Exchange network of sites has a role with this title.

What is this role about? Is the job description published anywhere?

Comment: This seems like a question that would set in motion a chain of responses that would no longer attempt to answer the actual question :)

Comment: If that happens, I hope they'll get down-voted, flagged etc. It's a simple question, that is intended to be taken at face value.

Comment: The role seems quite self-explanatory. "Director" is a fairly standard title, at least in US companies, and I think we all know what "Public Q&A" is.

Comment: @CodyGray I for one would like to know what their responsibilities are and where they are situated in the chain of command. I am not American, and I have never worked for a corporate, so I'm pretty ignorant (in the true sense of the word) about these issues.

Comment: Maybe try and find the original job posting for the role and see if they had any role requirements. Doubtful though...

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I think we can deduce where the role ISN'T in the hierarchy based on https://stackoverflow.com/company/management -- it isn't at the top table. Director is such a common title as to be effectively meaningless, but I suspect the role reports to Stack Overflow’s CTO.  Wouldn't hazard a guess at responsibilities other than 'all the free stuff SE do').

Comment: When you get hired by Stack Overflow as anything else than dev, you apparently either get the title Manager or Director.

Comment: I also wondered in a related comment yesterday ~"what a "director of..." is doing for 8 hours per day". It's a **very** difficult subject, though: I would understand if SE decided to not share details here - we're already at a point where the person is blamed for things of which we don't know who is *actually* responsible for. An actual job description *could* help, including information about the *responsibilities* and the *authorities*, and the degree of *accountability* (!). But **not** making statements could help to keep the "benefit of doubt" for this and future situations.

Comment: Not sure about questions but answers certainly aren't coming, or if they are, they certainly aren't public.

Comment: Related (Stack Overflow blog, 2019-08-19): *[Meet the Public Q&A team](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/meet-the-public-qa-team/)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen not really helpful, we just know that the Director has a cat called Tea, and is married to an engineer and they like setting up meetings...the Director; not the cat and the spouse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I love how you had to clarify what "they" refers to, and I wonder whether Chipps's niece and cat have agreed to be referred to as "she".

Comment: @ace_HongKongIndependence Just showing that "they" can be ambiguous, but the solution would have been easy: *We just know that the Director, who has a cat called Tea, and is married to an engineer, **likes** setting up meetings.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA Careful. Whether or not avoiding pronouns like that is compliant with the CoC is still part of the debate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: OK, the task for you now is to find the blog post (or similar) that was published when Sara got the position (it is somewhere).

Comment: Meanwhile, unexpected connection found: *"[Herding Code 204: Sara J. Chipps and George Stocker on Jewelbots](https://herdingcode.com/herding-code-204-sara-j-chipps-and-george-stocker-on-jewelbots/)"*

Comment: To those voting to close: this is very much on-topic and specific. It is possible that it may not have been asked with the best intentions in mind, but that doesn't make it off-topic or POB. If you feel that the question isn't a good one, you can use your downvote. That's what they are *for*.

Comment: I don't know, but I Googled the title and found only Sara Chipps. It made me laugh.

Comment: @EricDuminil no, it isn't. You can use "they" with male and female genders. However, note that I never mentioned the Director by name in the comments. The comments are example of gender-free language, e.g. "spouse" could refer to any gender. Taken to extreme, it soon becomes absurd but for comments and examples it's fine, it also adds an element of distance between speaker/writer and the statement.

Comment: @Mari-LouA they is fine for someone with unknown pronouns, but you should probably *"Use stated pronouns (when known)."*

Comment: Lol @ voting to close as primarily opinion based; a job description isn't opinionated, but if it is, it's a pretty useless position

Comment: I take it the current Director of Public Q&A has been in the role a relatively short time.  Was there someone else in the role previously, or is this a recently created position?

Comment: I have now made a [list of pages with all the Stack Overflow blog posts](http://pmortensen.eu/world2/?p=89), all the way back to 2008 (there are 5 blog posts per page, with an excerpt for each). There is a little bit of annotation, with many of blog posts often referenced here on meta.

Comment: [The HTTPS version](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/10/the-secret-index-of-all-stack-overflow-blog-posts/) in case it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems that "Public Q&A" are the question-and-answer sites accessible and usable by the public, as opposed to (edit:) [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) where only a limited set of people can become members. This includes several tiers - Basic, Business, Enterprise, where the latter is not hosted together with the public sites. Teams would be "Non-public Q&A" I guess.

So, it seems the Director of "Public Q&A" directs the development, design and engineering efforts of the entire public Stack Exchange network, and answers to Mary Ferguson, VP of Engineering; who in turn answers to David Fullerton, the company CTO.

In the context of the recent, uh, events, that means, in particular: "Public Q&A" does not include public relations, engagement with the public, being the public face of anything, or making SE-Inc-held information public which wasn't that way before.

---

See also the blog post [Meet the Public Q&A team](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/meet-the-public-qa-team/) linked to by @PeterMortensen.

Comment: As I understand it the reporting structure is Director -> VP -> C-suite. So there’s at least notionally be the VP of Engineering between the two positions.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: It's not clear to me whether the [leadership team](https://stackoverflow.com/company/management) has VPs per se. Also, what do you mean by "C-suite".

Comment: C suite is a slang term to encompass any C-Level execs; CTO, CEO, CFO, CMO, etc. Mary Ferguson is the VP of engineering at Stack Overflow and lies between directors and the CTO.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Ok, edited accordingly.